# jQuery Dialog to send email

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, email

Bit of a strange question. I'm trying to send an email from a jQuery dialog box but it seems that I'm stuck on sending the values from the input to hiddenfields to be able to send.

Here is the jQuery I use...

**javascript**

```
function sendEmail() {
   $("#email").dialog({
       modal: true,
       width: 550          
    });
  }
```

And here is the div that is uses.

**HTML**

```
<div class="popUpStyle" title="Send Email" id="email" style="display: none">
        <asp:Label ID="lblTo" runat="server" Text="To: "></asp:Label><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSendTo" Text=""></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblFrom" runat="server" Text="From: "></asp:Label><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSendFrom" Text="Training.Registration@JeffWyler.com"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text="Subject: "></asp:Label><input id="tbSubject" type="text"/>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblBody" runat="server" Text="Message:"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <input ID="tbMessage" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" Width="50px" Font-Size="smaller" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="btnSend_Click" />
    </div>
```

**C# Code Behind**

```
//Button Click Event
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(lblSendTo.Text));
msg.From = new MailAddress("Training.Registration@example.com");
msg.Subject = hfSubject.Value.ToString();
msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
msg.Body = tbMessage.Text;

//CONFIGURE SMTP OBJECT
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.example.com");

//SEND EMAIL
smtp.Send(msg);
```

The problem is that I'm not sure how to write the values in the input to a hiddenfield or another control on the serverside to be able to send the email. I know that the values are deleted once the send button is clicked. This does end up sending the email (on another button click, I display the lblSendTo as the recipients email address) but without the fields that need to be entered in, such as subject and the body of the message. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: u want the subject and message entered in the textboxes in code behind ?

Comment: Sorta, the inputs are in the div with the id="email." I know that I'm unable to send emails directly from jquery as sending emails are a server side function. So I have the inputs subject and message that show in the "email" popup. What I'm assuming I have to do, is save those values in the input to a hiddenfield and then be able to send the subject and the message from the serverside?

Comment: why do you need hiddenfield ?

Comment: You could use ajax with page method to send mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to use asp textboxes, and the text inside them should be available in the server side

**Based on your comment : Please notice the update**

The Apparent problem  is that your dialog is not getting appended inside the form, hence the values from the textboxes are not sent in the request during postback.

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="sendEmail()">Send email</a> // Assuming this is the anchor used to open the dailog, you can change it your way

    <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text="Subject: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbSubject" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblBody" runat="server" Text="Message:"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbMessage" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" Width="50px" Font-Size="smaller" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="btnSend_Click"  />
```

In your code behind

```
    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(lblSendTo.Text));
    msg.From = new MailAddress("Training.Registration@example.com");
    msg.Subject = tbSubject.Text;
    msg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    msg.Body = tbMessage.Text;
```

Now the script

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function () { // create the dialog right when the document is ready
     jQuery("#email").dialog({
       autoOpen: false,
       modal: true,
       width: 550          
     });
     jQuery("#email").parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first")); // This will append the dialog to the form ensuring values are sent during postback.
   });

   function sendEmail() {
    jQuery('#email').dialog('open'); // Open the dialog now
    return false;
   }
```

Comment: I have tried the asp textboxes. I've been sending blank subjects and body's during testing. From what I have gathered in when searching is that the button posts back but removes the values from the textboxes before it can send.

Comment: ok when do you call this sendmail() function, i mean on which buttons click ?

Comment: You are top diggity. All I needed was the parent().appendTo line. Great work and thanks for all the help!